# Terminal takes too much time to install little things

Tags: react-native, react-redux, npm-install

I'm working on react native project first time but the issue when I install little things from terminal like `npm install react-native-elements --save` so it will take too much time to load or install like 45 - 50 minutes. Please let me know if there is any solution to get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out next settings: 
`npm config set progress false` 
`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/`

Also you should update your NPM with the next command:
`npm install -g npm`

Also the problem could be your drive. HDD works better with larger files than with smaller ones

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using Yarn instead of npm. Because Yarn is faster than npm and you can install all libraries using it. Fast, reliable and secure dependency management - this is the promise of Yarn, the new dependency manager created by the engineers of Facebook.

You can find more information about Yarn and how install it here:
https://waverleysoftware.com/blog/yarn-vs-npm/